# getting value in float data type in c++

Tags: c++

I am dividing a small number with big number. Basically its a code to show cpu usage and wastage. and also it is calculating its utilization. but when I divide instead of some value in points the result is always zero.
even I am using float but it is not solving m problem.
I want to get my answer of cpu utilization and cpu wastage

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int totalmonotime=0;
    int totalutilization=0;
    int totalwastage=0;
    int tproc=0;
    int dump=0;
    double mono_u=0;
    double mono_w=0;

    cout<<"Enter Number of Process"<<"\n";      
    cin>>dump;

    if(dump>=1)
    {
        tproc=dump;
    }else
        cout<<"wrong input"<<"\n";


    int u[tproc];
    int w[tproc];
    for(int i =1;i<=tproc;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter "<<i<<" process's Utiizaton"<<"\n";
        cin>>u[i];
        cout<<"Enter "<<i<<" process's Wastage"<<"\n";
        cin>>w[i];
    }



    cout<<"Mono Programing"<<"\n";  
    for(int i=1;i<=tproc;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=u[i];j++)
        {
            cout<<"=";
        }
        for(int j=1;j<=w[i];j++)
        {
            cout<<"+";

        }
    }

    cout<<"\n";


    int x=0;
    cout<<"\n"<<"Multi Programing"<<"\n";
    for(int i=1;i<=tproc;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=u[i];j++)
        {
            cout<<"=";

        }
        for(int j=1;j<=w[i];j++)
        {
            cout<<"+";
        }
        cout<<"\n";


        for(int k=1;k<=u[i]+x;k++)
        {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        x=x+u[i];

    }

    for(int d=1;d<=tproc;d++)
    {

    totalwastage=totalwastage+w[d];
    totalutilization=totalutilization+u[d];

    }
    cout<<"\n"<<"total wastage = "<<totalwastage<<"\n";
    cout<<"total utilization = "<<totalutilization<<"\n";
    totalmonotime=totalwastage+totalutilization;
    cout<<"total time for mono programing is "<<totalmonotime<<"\n";
    cout<<"total time for multi programing"<<"\n";
    mono_u=(totalutilization/totalmonotime)*100;
    cout<<"\n"<<"CPU  utilization for mono programing ="<<mono_u<<"\n";
    mono_w=(totalwastage/totalmonotime)*100;
    cout<<"CPU  wastage for mono programing ="<<mono_w;
}
```

`

Comment: `int u[tproc];` and `int w[tproc];` are **non-standard** syntax. Variable-Length Arrays are an extension that only a few C++ compilers support. Don't rely on it, use `std::vector` instead.  In any case, you are performing integer division, not floating-point division, so of course any division result that would be less than 1 would produce an integer 0.

Comment: @RemyLebeau... that is true VLA's aren't part of C++

Answer (score 4):

your division is integer division:
`totalutilization/totalmonotime`... you can change one to float to perform the division in float style => `(double)totalutilization/(double)totalmonotime` (only one cast is really needed, but it gives your intent more clearly)

also know that if you were to premultiply the small number by 1000 or something, you might end up with a more precise answer (albeit off by the factor of 1000)

Comment: Thank's it really worked out, by just changing the data type to double.

Comment: @hamzashahid if you want to learn more you can read up on integer and float promotion rules in C and C++ there are some other gotchas in there about doing math with different sized int types and signed and unsigned types. It would be helpful to read them in the spec, even if you don’t 100% understand them right away, you will have a heightened awareness as to when things might not behave as you would guess.